# showDialogPopup Refresh Page after Click

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, function

I have a dialog box which displays an `OK` button once the process completes.

I would like to refresh the page once user clicks OK.

However, in my existing code, there isn't a code to handle the behaviour after clicking OK.

Below is my current code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: wsurl + "BackendRequest",
    data: '{ sDomain : "' + domain + '", sUserName : "' + username '"}',

    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        document.getElementById('btnGenerate').disabled = true;
        showDialogPopup('Generate Request', data.d);
        //window.location.reload();
    },
    error: function (objXMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        showDialogPopup('Generate Request', data.d);
        //window.location.reload();
    }
});
```

The current `window.location.reload();` refreshes the page immediately.

Is there a way to refresh the page only after user clicks `OK` in the `showDialogPopup` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write an onclick event for your "Ok" button.
try the code below:

```
<a onclick="OpenModal()">Open Modal</a>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <button onclick="ReloadPage()">Ok</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
//Opens the popup
function OpenModal() {
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
}

//Reloads the page
function ReloadPage() {
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) popup modal with return type boolean

```
 success: function (data) {
    const isConfirmed = confirm('Generate Request');

   if(isConfirmed) {
     console.log('Ok button clicked', data.d)
     window.location.reload();
   }
}
```